# Marketo - How to save complex object in Lead Database?

Tags: marketo

I was asked to store leads like below in Marketo's lead database through rest api "POST /rest/v1/leads.json".

```
{
  "action": "createOnly",
  "lookupField": "email",
  "input": [{
      "email": "kjashaedd-1@klooblept.com",
      "firstName": "Kataldar-1",
      "postalCode": "04828",
      "property": [{
          "type": "land",
          "status": "available"
        },
        {
          "type": "car",
          "status": "sold out"
        },
        {
          "type": "bike",
          "status": "sold out"
        },
        {
          "type": "laptops",
          "status": "available"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "email": "kjashaedd-2@klooblept.com",
      "firstName": "Kataldar-2",
      "postalCode": "04828",
      "property": [{
          "type": "land",
          "status": "sold out"
        },
        {
          "type": "car",
          "status": "available"
        },
        {
          "type": "bike",
          "status": "sold out"
        },
        {
          "type": "laptops",
          "status": "available"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Input field is not in flat json structure. What could be the best approach? Do I really need to use custom objects in this case? Can I dump "property" object as it is in the lead database and use velocity script to parse it ?

Answer (score 0):

If 'Property' is a custom object, you'll want to call that separately for the record and associated the record with that object via the [custom object](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/lead-database/custom-objects/#create_and_update) API

So you can push (create) the record first and then associate (add) the custom object to the record.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `List<Dictionary<string,object>>` in C# and retrieve the data and then store it using Entity Framework.

I am considering .Net framework in this case